# BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor

Tags: android, image, android-layout, bitmap, android-imageview

I need to upload a large image. The right way would be to use BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor with inSampleSize options. But the problem, that the image is still to big to fit in memory on some devices. Is there a way, to somehow recieve an InputStream of a scaled image instead of bitmap?

Or can you suggest any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Always the best place to start is the provided documentation.. they provide sample code of how to [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

start from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), it'll help you Load Large Bitmaps Efficiently

Comment: You either haven't read my question, or the documentation. I wrote, that I tried inSampleSize, that your link suggests.